How to solve the Product sales analysis question for SQL
This is my sql query:
SELECT 
    product_id, YEAR as first_year, quantity, price 
FROM 
    Sales 
WHERE 
    (product_id, YEAR) IN (SELECT product_id, MIN(YEAR) 
                           FROM Sales 
                           GROUP BY product_id);

I want the output to be as follows



product_id
first_year
quantity
price




100
2008
10
5000


200
2011
15
9000



But I'm getting this error:

42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server] An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','. (4145) (SQLExecDirectW)'


Which SQL language are you using exactly?

Can you give the sample data that would match your sample output? This part WHERE (product_id, YEAR) looks totally wrong syntax.  Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

SQL Server doesn't do Tuple WHEREs like postgres. You can use the standard TOP 1 of group duplicate for this
